# Rails ActiveRecord date parsing for i18n (specifically european date formats)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, date, internationalization

I'm working on a rails project for an Australian website.  As a result, they want to be able to enter date formats in the more european-standard of 'dd/mm/yyyy' rather than the US-centric 'mm/dd/yyyy'.  I have an ActiveRecord model with a Date field.  I'm using jQuery's datepicker to provide the date select on a text field, and have it setting the date to a proper format.  But, when I try to save the record, it gets the date wrong.  Even when I've set the custom date formats in an intializer according to the i18n guide.

```
>> b = BlogPost.new
>> b.posted_on = '20/07/2010'
=> "20/07/2010"
>> b.posted_on 
=> nil
>> b.posted_on = '07/20/2010'
=> Tue, 20 Jul 2010
```

It seems that Rails is just using Date.parse to convert the string into a Date object.  Is there any way to fix this for the whole project?  I don't want to have to write custom code for each model.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Date
  class << self
    def _parse_with_us_format(date, *args)
      if date =~ %r{^(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$}
        _parse_without_us_format("#{$3.length == 2 ? "20#{$3}" : $3}-#{$1}-#{$2}", *args)
      else
        _parse_without_us_format(date, *args)
      end
    end
    alias_method_chain :_parse, :us_format
  end
end
```

Comment: solution works and is simple. If you need more inclusive solutions see [delocalize](https://github.com/clemens/delocalize) or [i18n_alchemy](https://github.com/carlosantoniodasilva/i18n_alchemy).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the default date format (in config/environment.rb)

```
ActiveSupport::CoreExtensions::Time::Conversions::DATE_FORMATS.
    merge!(default => '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
```

Find out more here http://blog.nominet.org.uk/tech/2007/06/14/date-and-time-formating-issues-in-ruby-on-rails/